# Subarray Sum Equals K

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

Given an array of integers and an integer k, you need to find the total number of continuous subarrays whose sum equals to k.

Trying to solve this problem off of [leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/subarray-sum-equals-k/) and not sure exactly where I'm stuck and how to get to the correct solution. It fails for the case nums = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] and k = 0, the answer I get is 10 when it should really be  55

```
class Solution(object):
    def subarraySum(self, nums, k):
        count = 0
        for i in range(0, len(nums)): 
            count += self.driver(nums, k, nums[i], i+1)
        return count


    def driver(self, nums, target, curr, index): 
        if curr == target:
            return 1
        else:
            for i in range(index, len(nums)): 
                return self.driver(nums, target, curr + nums[i], i+1)
            return 0
```

Comment: What do you think `return`ing in a loop does?

Answer (score 0):

This would be easier with the accumulate function from itertools.

```
from itertools import accumulate
def subarraySum(a,k):
    return sum( list(accumulate(a[i:])).count(k) for i in range(len(a)) )

print(subarraySum([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],0)) # 55
```

Just let accumulate() do the cumulative sum from each position in the array up to the end and count the number of times it arrives at the desired value.  This will cover the case of zero as well as negative numbers.

if you're not allowed to use an imported module, you could write you own accumulate iterator:

```
def accumulate(a):
    s = 0
    for v in a: s+=v; yield s
```